# Who should analyze mouse input in MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, typescript

I am pretty new to MVC, and I want to do things right from the beginning so :
I am building an MVC web app in jquery/html; I must know where the mouse is on the screen and do different stuff depending on that position.
Should the View take the mouse position and, depending on where it is, call different functions of the Controller, or should the View simply send the mouse position to the controller who then chooses what to do with it ?
Is there an example of MVC in web app that I could look throught ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View**: Get the coordinates where the user interaction happened (mouse click). Send the coordinates + any additional information to Controller.

**Controller**: Get the details of the user interaction (mouse click) and decide what to do with it.